# Stylus: Is there a Way to make this DRYer

Tags: dry, stylus

I have a number of hashes that I wish to loop through.

For example, I have a colors hash:

```
colors = {
  red: #f00f00,
  green: #78f000,
  blue: #0090f0,
}
```

And a sizes hash:

```
fontSize = {
  small:  14px,
  base:   16px,
  large:  18px
}
```

I then loop through these hashes.  Here is simplified example:

```
for name, color in colors
  .{name}
    background-color: color

for name, size in fontSize
  .{name}
    font-family: size
```

What I want to know is whether or not there is a DRYER to do this.  I.e., I don't want to have to rewrite the for...in loop over and over again (since it's the same structure for each hash.

Is there a way that this can be done (and, if so, how)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a function with the loop and use the arguments to get the classname and set the property you need:

**Stylus**

```
colors = {
  red: #f00f00,
  green: #78f000,
  blue: #0090f0
}

fontSize = {
  small:  14px,
  base:   16px,
  large:  18px
}

loop(hashname, prop)
  for class, value in hashname
    .{class}
      {prop}: value


loop(colors, background-color)

loop(fontSize, font-size)
```

**Output**

```
.red {
  background-color: #f00f00;
}
.green {
  background-color: #78f000;
}
.blue {
  background-color: #0090f0;
}
.small {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.base {
  font-size: 16px;
}
.large {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll give that a try.

Comment: I have discovered another potential solution -- but it has a different problem that needs addressing.  If you are able, would you mind taking a look at it:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48927820/conditionally-show-hash-values-in-stylus

Comment: I was trying get a solution for your other question, I'm not sure if is possible to do