# Conditionally Show Hash Values in Stylus

Tags: conditional-statements, stylus

I have the following hash:

```
styles = {
   fontSize: {
     use: true,
     values: {
       sm: .875rem,
       base: 1rem,
       lg: 1.125rem,
     }
   },
   fontWeight: {
     use: false,
     values: {
       light: 300,
       normal: 400,
       bold: 700,
     }
   }
}
```

I would like to create a for in loop that processes the values only if `use` is set to true.

I have this code which will loop through the different style types:

```
for style in styles
  items = styles[style]
  for item in items
    {item}
      for property, value in items[item]
          {property} value
```

What I can't figure out is how to test if `use` is set to true or false and to then process (or not) the values.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a [conditional statement](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/conditionals.html#unless), such as an `if <value>` statement, inside of the loop?

e.g.

```
for style in styles
  {style}
    items = styles[style]
    if items.use
        for property, value in items.values
            {property} value
```

View [demo online here.](http://stylus-lang.com/try.html#?code=styles%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20fontSize%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20use%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20values%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sm%3A%20.875rem%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20base%3A%201rem%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20lg%3A%201.125rem%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20fontWeight%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20use%3A%20false%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20values%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20light%3A%20300%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20normal%3A%20400%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bold%3A%20700%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afor%20style%20in%20styles%0A%20%20%7Bstyle%7D%0A%20%20%20%20items%20%3D%20styles%5Bstyle%5D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20items.use%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20property%2C%20value%20in%20items.values%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7Bproperty%7D%20value)